# Problems viewing ASTER imagery in google earth engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth

I am trying to view ASTER imagery for Mount Spurr from 2004 to 2006.
I am loading the imagery in a list "listOfImages" and access them for viewing via listOfImages.get(). Despite all images appear in my list and are loaded as layers, only a fraction of them are visible on the map when clicking on the specific layer. The code I use is as follows:

```
// Load a landsat image and select three bands for Mount Spurr
// Mount Spurr
// start: 2004-03-01
// end: 2006-05-30


 var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('ASTER/AST_L1T_003')
              .filterDate('2004-03-01','2006-05-30')
              .sort('system:time_start',false)

// filter imagery
var Image_filtered = dataset.filterBounds(geometry_Mt_Spurr)
 print(Image_filtered.size())

// convert to list
var listOfImages = Image_filtered.toList(Image_filtered.size());
print('List:',listOfImages);

// Get the size of the image list (this is a server side ee.Number object).
var len = listOfImages.size();
// build and show layers in GEE
len.evaluate(function(l) {
  for (var i=0; i < l; i++) {
    var img = ee.Image(listOfImages.get(i));
    Map.addLayer(img, {bands:['B3N','B02','B01']}, 'Img'+i.toString(),false);
    print('Img-'+i.toString());
    print(img.date());
  } 
})
```

The ASTER imagery has been loaded as an ImageCollection (ee.ImageCollection) and geometry_Mt_Spurr is just a rectangle over the area of interest.

Working with less images in the list did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the "Inspector" tab on the right-hand-side and click inside your geometry. You'll notice that some of your images have one or more bands masked. Each image has an `ORIGINAL_BANDS_PRESENT` property. You can use this to filter out images missing your required bands.

```
var Image_filtered = dataset
  .filterBounds(geometry_Mt_Spurr)
  .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('ORIGINAL_BANDS_PRESENT', 'B01'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('ORIGINAL_BANDS_PRESENT', 'B02'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('ORIGINAL_BANDS_PRESENT', 'B3N'))
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/ccaf974fedd97b2d7103982271394289

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Daniel. So, is it correct, that images with masked bands have not been acquired with the corresponding bands? Or is it possible to "unmask" them?

Comment: I don't know the reason why they are masked. You can unmask them to any value of your choice, but there is no "hidden" value that you can revert to.

Comment: According to the text in the catalog: "Not all 14 bands were collected in each scene. An asset property named ORIGINAL_BANDS_PRESENT contains the list of bands that are present in each scene."

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!